# Was bedeutet "rechthaberisch"?

Tags: meaning, vocabulary

Ich habe ein bisschen im Internet gesucht, konnte aber nicht finden, was es genau bedeutet.

Also wenn jemand sagt

> Ja, dein Problem ist, dass du rechthaberisch bist.

Was kann das bedeuten?

Ich habe trotzdem Folgendes gefunden:

> rechthaberisch
>
> [Adj.; abwertend] eigensinnig auf seinem Recht, auf seiner Meinung beharrend;
> rechthaberisch sein (stets) auf seinem Recht, seiner Meinung beharren

Kann jemand bitte in einfachen Worten erklären, was es bedeutet?

Comment: Was meinst Du mit "trotzdem"? Was meinst Du mit "genau"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Im Grunde wird in deinem Quote schon alles erklärt. *Rechthaberisch* bedeutet schlichtweg, dass du auf deiner Meinung beharrst und dich durch nichts von dieser abbringen lässt – ungeachtet dessen, ob du recht hast oder nicht.

In *rechthaberisch* steckt *recht haben* und Letzteres ist *to be right* im Englischen. *Rechthaberisch* bedeutet *self-opinionated*, *dogmatic* oder einfach *to insist on something*.

Wenn du also *rechthaberisch* bist, hast du eine Meinung und bestehst darauf, dass sie als richtig und allgemeingültig akzeptiert wird, selbst wenn andere überzeugende Gegenargumente liefern.

Comment: Vorsicht!
Das Titulieren der Rechthaberei dient manchen schlichten Geistern auch als Waffe.
Und wenn du Recht hast, wo ist dann Dein Problem?

Comment: Als Rechthaber kann ich das so nicht stehen lassen. Wer wirklich Recht hat ist für die Frage, ob jmd. rechhaberisch ist, unerheblich. Dass jmd. wider besseres Wissen darauf besteht Recht zu haben mag auch vorkommen - aber die Ausnahme sein. Und die Gegenargumente können nicht überzeugend sein, denn im *überzeugend* steckt der Erfolg des Überzeugens drin. Offenbar haben sie denjenigen aber nicht überzeugt.